# Flutter "showDialog" with Navigator.pop()

Tags: dart, flutter

I have problem with showDialog, when i press nothing happens but if i use `Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/screen1")` it works. I can not run `Navigator.pop(context)`, it does not return any errors.

```
_showDialog(BuildContext context) {
return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: new Text("Alert Dialog title"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text("Back"),
            onPressed: () {
              //Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/screen1");
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    });}
```

In my build() :

```
IconButton(
iconSize: 30.0,
onPressed: () => _showDialog(context),
icon: Icon(
  Icons.clear,
  color: Colors.white,
 ),
```

)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling `Navigator.of(context).pop();` instead of `Navigator.pop(context);`

Comment: What's the difference between those two ?

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian AFAIK, both are supposed to do some work. Maybe one of them is added in latest version of the SDK.

Comment: please kindly explain how this answer solve the problem?

Comment: See source of flutter, both is same ```static void pop<T extends Object>(BuildContext context, [ T result ]) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop<T>(result);
  }```

Answer (score 26):

had the same issue .having  `useRootNavigator: false,` in showDialog params solved my issue .

Comment: Can you please explain what it does?

Comment: The useRootNavigator argument is used to determine whether to push the dialog to the Navigator furthest from or nearest to the given context. By default, useRootNavigator is true and the dialog route created by this method is pushed to the root navigator. It can not be null.

Answer (score 10):

The above answer should be accepted for this question, just elaborating the above answer

```
return showDialog(
context: context,
useRootNavigator: false, //this property needs to be added 
builder: (BuildContext context) {....});
```

Comment: It worked in my case as well, but I don't understand what is it for. Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Answer (score 8):

Use pop() two times:-

Navigator.of(context).pop();
Navigator.of(context).pop();

Reason: first pop function dismiss the dialog and Second pop function close the screen

Answer (score 4):

For closing dialogs, you can also use:

`Navigator.pop(context, true);`

Source: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html

Comment: You only need to use `true` or `false` if previous screen is expecting some result.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have nested/multiple Navigators, you can also use the `pop` method as shown below (notice the named parameter `rootNavigator` set to true):

```dart
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
```

As suggested by others, I tried setting the `useRootNavigator` in the `showDialog` as `false` but this way the *barrierColor* wasn't covering the whole screen (it was only covering the screen displayed by Navigator object the dialog was in).

In summary, you can use the way showed above if you have nested navigators and want to achieve having the *barrierColor* covering the whole screen.